# Change cache location for Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm using Selenium 4.16.0 for Python, on Windows 10.

How can I change the default cache location ?

The default cache location is "~/user/.cache", a directory.

But I get errors since another program use "~/user/.cache", a file.

Comment: If you are talking about Selenium manager's cache, it'll check two environment variables.    These are "SE_MANAGER_PATH" and "CACHE_PATH_ENV".  CACHE_PATH_ENV defaults to user home if not set. SE_MANAGER_PATH is where the manager's executable is extracted.  (I think temporarily...)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firefox, the alternative solution is that you can set the `--profile` option to specify a custom user data directory.

```
firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
firefox_options.add_argument("--profile=/path/to/custom/cache/location")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I get this : `selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Failed to set preferences: unknown error`